# change the script everytime I work on the new scratch file in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Why I do have to change the script path manually according to the new scratch file I make on pycharm, Is there anyway the pycharm would automatically make the changes in the script path as I make new scratch file ?

Comment: Use a regular file

Comment: nope, it did not work